# RabbitMQ Publish via Management HTTP API not_authorised but works in Web UI

Tags: rabbitmq

I tried to publish a message to both the default exchange and also some other exchange via the HTTP Management API but I always get back an authorization error.

```
curl -i -u myuser:mypw -XPOST -d'{"properties":{},"routing_key":"my_key","payload":"my body","payload_encoding":"string"}' https://myinstance.rmq.cloudamqp.com/api/exchanges/vhost/myvhost/publish
```

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.14.2
Date: Mon, 01 Apr 2019 05:27:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 53
Connection: keep-alive
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'
vary: accept, accept-encoding, origin

{"error":"not_authorised","reason":"Access refused."}%
```

I tried it both on a self hosted RabbitMQ (installed via helm on k8s) and our CloudAMQP instance.

But if I login on the Management Web UI with the very same user then I can publish a message to the exchange and also consume from a queue.
I expect that the Management Web UI just uses the HTTP API for performing this actions so I am confused why it works when I do it via the UI.

Reading all vhost on the other hand works also with the HTTP API.

```
curl -i -u myuser:mypw https://myinstance.rmq.cloudamqp.com/api/vhosts
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Can somebody explain to me whats going on there? What puzzels me the most is the fact that it works on the UI using the same user:pw.

Answer (score 6):

I figured out the problem, I did use the wrong URL path.

For vhost: `/` and the default exchange it should be:
`http://myinstance.rmq.cloudamqp.com/api/exchanges/%2F/amq.default/publish`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using the CloudAmqp free plan, I needed to use my user name as vHost in rhe URL:

[https://myinstance.rmq.cloudamqp.com/api/exchanges/[myrandomusernamefromfreeplan]/amq.default/publish](https://myinstance.rmq.cloudamqp.com/api/exchanges/%5Bmyrandomusernamefromfreeplan%5D/amq.default/publish)